# Views filter on field being either empty or equal to uid

Tags: 7, views

I have a views filter on a particular field being empty (`Is empty (NULL)`).

However, I would like to have it check on the field being either empty **or** equal to the current user's uid. I would like to do this programmatically in a custom module, so without installing a contributed module.

The field in question is `$node->field_quality_personal[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']`. So this field can be either `empty`, or it can contain a `uid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the way to fix this. The answer is twofold:

**First** create two filters: one for the field being empty and one for the field being equal to the string "uid". Then as a Filter Criteria option, choose `And/Or, Rearrange` and add the `Or` condition:

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

**Second** implement `hook_views_query_alter()` to replace the "uid" string we added earlier with the actual user `uid`:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 *
 * Search for 'personal' field to be empty or equal to uid.
 */
function example_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'myview') {
    foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
      foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {
        if ($condition['field'] == 'table.field_quality_personal' && $condition['value'] == 'uid') {
          global $user;
          $condition['value'] = $user->uid;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That's it!